# Creating APN Development Profile Error, "Valid signing identity not found"

Tags: xcode4.5, apple-push-notifications, ios6.1

I have an iOS App projects that needs push notifications. I followed tutorials on how to create a provisioning profiles for APN such as

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nFjEcLCTPM0

but I am always having this error in `Provisioning Profile` section under `Devices`

`Valid Signing Identity not found`

and in Code Signing Identities i have the error

`Profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in your settings`

Or is it somehow related to the fact that I already have 2 existing provisioning profiles for an app? I will greatly appreciate tips to fix this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Create the provisioning profile using xCode organizer instead of iOS Dev Centre.

1. Generate CSR using Keychain Access. You can specify any email
   address
2. Create an APP ID at iOS Dev Center. Specify the `certSigningRequest` file created in step 1
3. Create the Provisioning Profile using xCode organizer
4. Generate the PEM files